# Multiple persons flip biased coins multiple times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've been trying to solve this seemingly easy problem for some time, but I'm not that well-versed in probability, so I thought I would ask.

Let there be $N$ persons each with identical biased coins that land heads with probability $p$ (and tails $1-p$). In each trial all persons flip their coins simultaneously and each person whose coin lands on heads is eliminated.

Then the question is the following:

> What is the probability that every person is eliminated after $t$ trials?

It should be equivalent to the probability of everyone landing heads at least once in the $t$ first trials, and just ignoring that people are eliminated.

I'm also interested in the slightly different question:

> What is the probability that the people are eliminated as a group in exactly trial number $t$? (In the sense that there still was at least one not eliminated in trial $t-1$, but everyone eliminated in trial $t$).

I understand that if we were simply looking at one person, we could just use the binomial distribution to calculate the probability of having one "success" in $t$ throws, but I did not know how to continue after introducing multiple people.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Let $T$ be time of elimination. Then $P(T\le t)=(1-q^t)^N$ and $P(T=t)=P(T\le t)-P(T\le t-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right analysis of the first problem. 
We do the details because once we know how to solve the first problem, the second problem is easy.

The probability that after $t$ trials everybody is eliminated is the probability each has at least one head in $t$ trials, for we can imagine that even after being officially eliminated they keep flipping in another room.

The probability of at least one head in $t$ trials is $1-(1-p)^t$, so the probability they are all eliminated is $(1-(1-p)^t)^N$.

The probability that the *last elimination* occurs on the $t$-th trial is the probability they are all eliminated by time $t$, *minus* the probability they are all eliminated by time $t-1$. This is
$$(1-(1-p)^t)^N-(1-(1-p)^{t-1})^N.$$

Comment: +1. Thanks so much! Usually I would wait a little before accepting the answer, however this answers everything :).

Comment: You are welcome.